# Start a new Activity from non Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to start a new activity in non-Activity class that implements a `DialogListener` following is my code:

```
public class FacebookLoginDialog implements DialogListener {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    HomeActivity.showInLog(values.toString());

    Intent i1 = new Intent (this, SearchActivity.class);
    startActivity(i1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(DialogError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```

I can't start the new activity using intent in `onComplete` method, please help.

Thanks

Comment: try to change "this" to getApplicationContext(), or pass the context from an activity

Comment: Note that I want to start the activity when login done successfully that's why i have started activity in onComplete method

Comment: I have changed this to getApplicationContext(), but it couldn't solve my problem. Can you tell how exactly I should pass context from an activity? SearchActivity is the activity i want to start

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This doesn't work because you need a `Context` in order to start a new activity. You can reorganize your class into something like this:

```
public class FacebookLoginDialog implements DialogListener {
  private final Context context;

  public FacebookLoginDialog(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    HomeActivity.showInLog(values.toString());

    Intent i1 = new Intent (context, SearchActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i1);
  }

  //Other methods...
}
```

Then it will work.

Comment: I'd be worried about where the Context in the constructor came from.  Wouldn't (Activity).getContext() be better?

Comment: @Simon There is no `Activity.getContext()` method, activity is a context already.

Comment: Hmm.  13 hours working and too much wine with dinner.  I know what I meant, which was both wrong and to compound matters, incorrectly expressed.  Time to call it quits for the night...

Comment: Hi Malcolm I tried this too but it gives error on line   Intent i1 = new Intent (this, SearchActivity.class);.

Comment: I am sure it would really work but for now I am getting error on login . So can tell you is this worked 100%. Anyways Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Malcolm there is no error. And app runs fine but after login completion new ativity doesn't start. And I am waiting to accept your answer as soon as I solved my issue

Comment: @Nadeem Your are asking a wider question than the original one now. There can be different problems, for example, the method which launches the activity may not get called. This question is about correctly launching an activity, but figuring out what is wrong with the application in whole - that's different, there is not enough information here to answer it anyway. You may open a new question on that issue.

Comment: This can sometimes lead to the error and might even crash your app, so if you want to start new activity from the Non-Activity class you must add .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to your intent.

Comment: @AakashSharma Depends on what you want. If you are passing an activity as the context, usually you don't want to start as a new task. This is the case I covered in my answer. If you are not starting from an existing activity, you don't have much of a choice, of course.

Answer (score 13):

Pass context as constructor parameter and then try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It works on Samsung s4 but not in Galaxy Note 2 !! any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

use starActivity from non-activity class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR STRING");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share via...");
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Answer (score -1):

For Easy Usage you can a method for this particular method:

```java
public class Something
{
   public static void navigate(Context context,  Class<?> nameOfClass)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, nameOfClass);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

can be called in other class and method everytime by calling this:

```java
Something.navigate(activityName.this, classYourWantTONavigateTo.class);
```