# Sharing text on libgdx android

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to create a share button in a libgdx game. I've followed this guide https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code , but when calling the interface method, I get this error:

```
06-26 23:57:31.594: W/System.err(27789): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 23:57:31.596: W/System.err(27789):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3436)
06-26 23:57:31.597: W/System.err(27789):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3393)
06-26 23:57:31.599: W/System.err(27789):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3644)
06-26 23:57:31.601: W/System.err(27789):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3607)
06-26 23:57:31.602: W/System.err(27789):    at com.mimostudios.utils.Share.shareScore(Share.java:18)
06-26 23:57:31.603: W/System.err(27789):    at com.mimostudios.policecarracing.android.AndroidShare.shareScore(AndroidShare.java:15)
06-26 23:57:31.604: W/System.err(27789):    at com.mimostudios.policecarracing.MenuScreen.render(MenuScreen.java:47)
06-26 23:57:31.605: W/System.err(27789):    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
06-26 23:57:31.607: W/System.err(27789):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:414)
06-26 23:57:31.608: W/System.err(27789):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
06-26 23:57:31.609: W/System.err(27789):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

The method which the interface is calling is

```
12 public void shareScore(String title, String message) {
13  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
14  share.setType("text/plain");
15  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
16  try {
17      Intent finalIntent = Intent.createChooser(share, title); 
18      startActivity(finalIntent); 
19  } catch (Exception e) {
20      System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
21      e.printStackTrace();
22  }
23 }
```

And I've also added the Share Activity in the manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.mimostudios.utils.Share"></activity>
```

Any ideas?
If I am missing some relevant info, please let me know, is my first question!

Comment: Which is this line - at com.mimostudios.utils.Share.shareScore(Share.java:18) ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the numbers, I'll edit the original question.
Anyway, line 18 is 
   startActivity(finalIntent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution, based on this: [Start a new Activity from non Activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664463/start-a-new-activity-from-non-activity-class)

The class I was trying to use was extending from Activity, because I thought that's the only way for a class to start a new Activity.
However, is possible to start an Activity fron a non-Activity class if you pass the context to the constructor of that class. After that, you can call the method startActivity from the context.