# Risks when starting activity from application context?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

A singleton non-activity class manages the server API calls throughout the app. If communication fails, the manager class should start a login activity (`launchMode="singleTask"`).

The manager class does not hold a context, so the login activity is started from app context:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
App.getInstance().getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

`App.getInstance()` for that matter returns the singleton of the `MultiDexApplication` instance.

It seems to work.

Now, there are countless SO articles about [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664463/start-a-new-activity-from-non-activity-class) and [android contexts](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/which-context-should-i-use-in-android-e3133d00772c), but after reading many, I am still unsure if this poses any risks. Some SO answers suggest keeping a context reference via activity lifecycle observer, but I want to avoid any static reference and potential memory leak.

The only drawback I found is that the app context is "non-themed", but the activity looks as expected. So that doesn't seem to be an issue?

Are there any issues with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

> The only drawback I found is that the app context is "non-themed", but the activity looks as expected. So that doesn't seem to be an issue?

The activity has its own `Context`, which will be tied to its own theme. The "don't use an `Application` for UI" rule is more for things like inflating layouts — if you are in an activity, use the activity for that sort of work.

> Are there any issues with this approach?

I'm not a fan, having had to maintain an app for a while that took this approach:

- It will make testing the singleton difficult, particularly with that hard-coded reference to your `Application`
- The user may not appreciate your wiping out the back stack, unless you have some other means of returning the user to where she was at the time
- It will make doing background work difficult, as you should not be popping up an authentication activity out of the blue (to the point where it is banned on Android Q and higher)
- It might cause extra problems in multi-window environments (both split-screen and freeform)
- From a separation-of-concerns standpoint, this is just ugly (a non-UI singleton should not be doing UI things, such as showing UI)

So, technically, it should work. I would not do it this way (and, if I had my druthers, I'd've ripped out that implementation that I had to maintain).

Comment: How would you do it? I get your point that "a non-UI singleton should not be doing UI things". The manager class is the central point for all API calls. If the login session is revoked for example, who should the manager class notify? Every activity extends a base activity, and there is a main activity which is also `launchMode=singleTask`.

Comment: I could think of the manager class sending out a local broadcast and whichever activity is currently in foreground and receives it starts the login activity. That would decouple the manager class from UI. Also after login the user gets back to the activity where they have left off. Is that something you would suggest?

Comment: @Manuel: "If the login session is revoked for example, who should the manager class notify?" -- the caller. "Unauthorized" is an error condition. It is the responsibility of the caller to handle that, based on the details of who the caller is and what state the app is in. For example, a service caller might raise a `Notification` where an activity or fragment caller might display an authentication `DialogFragment`.